# calculating odd ratio in R when there is more than two categories

Tags: r

For the following dataset:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
  yes 181  93 141 186 198
  No  14  11  11  23  21
```

This is the data set
`data_frame(rating=1:5, No=c(167,82, 132, 182, 200), Yes=c(28, 22, 20, 27,` 29))

0 means presence of headache and 1 absence of headache, and 1 to 5 shows the rate of adherence to medication. How I can calculate odd ratio for this data? This is my code:

```
library (epiR)
epi.2by2(tbl_dow, method ='cohort.count', conf.level= 0.95)
```

But did not work. it has the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(est = cmOR.p, lower = cmOR.l, upper = cmOR.u) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Can you `dput()` the data necessary to reproduce this? `dput(tbl_dow)`.

Comment: @Hack-R, I edited the question. Is it OK now?

Comment: Where does the function `data_frame()` come from? Did you mean `data.frame()`? if so, this wouldn't work because `epi.2by2` accepts an object of class `table` not a data.frame. It might really be better to `dput()` the data.

Comment: Also I note that you're using the **2by2** version of the function and the shape of the data is not 2 by 2. It's 2x5.

Comment: @but there is no epi.2by5. I think I need to ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: That might be a way to go but can I ask why you never `dput()` your data? It would've made it a lot easier to help you and if you hover your pointer over the R tag to see the tag description, it's actually specified there in the 3rd sentence as how to include data in R questions...

Comment: Why the question is voted negative? What is wrong with it ?

Comment: It doesn't follow the MCVE requirement or the R tag description instructions on creating a reproducible example. That's why I kept asking you to `dput()` your data 3 times. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  From the tag description: *Please supplement your question with a minimal reproducible example. **Use dput() for data** and specify all non-base packages with library calls. For statistical questions please use http://stats.stackexchange.com.* You're also using a non-existing function called `data_frame` as mentioned earlier and the formatting is off.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c(181L, 14L), X2 = c(93L, 11L), X3 = c(141L, 
11L), X4 = c(186L, 23L), X5 = c(198L, 21L)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("0", 
"1"))
```

Assuming you want the odds ratio of each 0/1 per category, just use apply:

```
apply(df1,2, FUN=function(x) x[[2]]/sum(x))

        X1         X2         X3         X4         X5 
0.07179487 0.10576923 0.07236842 0.11004785 0.09589041
```

Comment: I think she's trying to do this on an object of class `table`. That's why I asked her to `dput()`.